# Read More bug all expand when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, slider, expand

i'll keep this simple as it is simple.

so i have a page that im using for tesmonials and i managed to add a read more function to each one and i wanted to keep the page clean and neat looking..

the read more function works, but heres my issue. since i have about 10 testmonials everytime i click on 1 read more the whole 10 posts expand at the same time.. any help please?

heres the HTML code

```
<p>something something something first</p>
<div style="width: 500px; padding: 10px;">
<br/><br/><a href="#" class="readMore">Read More</a>? <br/><br/>
<!-- BEGIN: Hidden Content. -->
<div class="content" style="display: none ; width:500px;">things things and stuff and more stuff and things </p></div>
<!-- END: Hidden Content. -->
```

and here is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.6.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Cache a reference to the hidden content.
    var hiddenContent = $("div.content");

    // Bind to the Read More link to toggle the
    $("a.readMore").click(

    function(event) {
        // Cancel the default event (this isn't a real link).
        event.preventDefault();
        // Check to see if the content is visible.
        if (hiddenContent.is(":visible")) {
            // Hide it slowly.
            hiddenContent.slideUp(3000);
        } else {
            // Show it slowly.
            hiddenContent.slideDown(3000);
        }
    });
</script>
```

any help will be great..  again  the issue it ( it works ) but when one -read more- is clicked all the other 10 posts expand as well.

Comment: The `$( "div.content" );` selector will select ***all*** div's with id=content.  Is this what you want?  Or do you only want one?

Answer (score 0):

You've got some malformed HTML there and the Jquery is not correct either.

First correct the HTML by removing the errant `</p>` tag and adding a closing `</div>` tag where appropriate. All those `<br />` tags are just bad practice. If you want spacing, add CSS padding to the anchor tag rather than adding a mess of break tags.

```
<p> something something something first</p>
<div style="width: 500px ;padding: 10px ;">
<a href="#" class="readMore">Read More</a>?

<div class="content" style="display: none ; width:500px;">things things and stuff and more stuff and things</div>
</div>
```

Next you need to target the hidden div which is related to the link preceding it. In order to do that, you need to move the var declaration **inside** the jquery function.

```
$( "a.readMore" ).click( function( event ){
event.preventDefault();
var hiddenContent = $(this).next(".content");

if (hiddenContent.is( ":visible" )){
    hiddenContent.slideUp(300);
} else {
    hiddenContent.slideDown(300);
} 
});
```

I've set up a [**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/ARxjd/) for you to see.

Comment: Scott   worked like magic..  thank you very much. and i will take your advice on fixing the breaks.. tbh i do know its a bad practice .. but i got lazy as its 3AM here and i just want to finish this.

Comment: @user2228806 if this solved your issue you should mark it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark on the left.